# Lightning Exchange

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

Can we modify the functionality of Apps available on Lightning Exchange?
Is there any possible way to modify the functionality of Apps available on Exchange?

What are Visual building Tools and Lightning Exchange?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is No, You can't modify them. You can use lab apps that are provided as unmanaged package or there is one filter "Editable Code" which you can use to identify apps that allow there code modification but they are very less <10. So most of the time you need to use them or write your own logic.

Visual building Tools are the tools which you can use to design /develop something using drag and drop(visually) eg: Lightning App builder.

Lightning Exchange is where you will find Lightning Component. I think it is just app exchange they have added some filter related to Lightning.

[Editing Components and Attributes After Installation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_attributes.htm)

Comment: any salesforce links to substantiate? Thank you.

Comment: @Sanky check my answer. There you find list of all components which you can edit or not.